# Adding Dimension to a Cropped Circle

Tags: crop

I'm trying to figure out how to make certain features stick out of a cropped circle image. For example, I have a portrait of someone that I have cropped into a circle, but I would like to have her hand that is waving be on top of he circle outline/outside of cropped circle to show some dimension. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways, this is made with **Photoshop**, **layers** and **masks**:

Photo by *Matthew Kane* for [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/nahUo1GhcrA)

[image: original]

[image: mask]

The **FRAME Layer** has a circular mask with just the exterior frame border effect, leaving clear the main part of the image:

[image: circle]

The **HAND/HAIR Layer** has no effects and a mask leaving clear the part that has to be over the frame:

[image: hand]

Comment: Perfectly reasonable answer, questionable result ;) haha

Comment: Too bad this effort may be wasted if the user returns to post -- "Oh, I meant with Illustrator/Sketch/Affinity/Gimp". `:)`

Comment: That's why I didn't use the super ultra defined top plus mask brush for the hair 